# Security issue with custom build decorator in Django

Tags: python, django

I am working with a custom build decorator in **Django**.

my **decorators.py**:

```
from django.contrib.auth import REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test

def industry_required(function=None, redirect_field_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME, login_url='app2:request_login'):
    actual_decorator = user_passes_test(
        lambda u: u.is_active and u.is_Industry,
        login_url=login_url,
        redirect_field_name=redirect_field_name
    )
    if function:
        return actual_decorator(function)
    return actual_decorator
```

Here `is_Industry` is a bool value, comes from models.py.

my **views.py**:

```
@method_decorator(industry_required, name='dispatch')
class industryDetails(DetailView):
    model = Industry
    template_name = 'app/industryDetails.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['inserted_text'] = "inserted text from EmployeeDetails of views.py"
        return context
```

in **urls.py**:

```
path('industryDetails/<int:pk>/', views.industryDetails.as_view(), name='industryDetails')
```

**models.py** also included if you need:

```
class myCustomeUser(AbstractUser):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique="True", blank=False)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)
    is_Employee = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_Inspector = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_Industry = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_Admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class Industry(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(myCustomeUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True, related_name='industry_releted_user')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    owner = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    license = models.IntegerField(null=True, unique=True)
    industry_extrafield = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

Now my problem is, suppose a user with having `primary_key=3`, can easily visite another user's data having `primary_key=2`, by using `http://127.0.0.1:8000/industryDetails/2/` (by changing the primary key in this address path). I need to stop this for my project. How can I code this in such a way that, any user can only visit his own details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That has nothing to do with the decorator itself, you simply need to filter prevent people from accessing another `Industry`, so:

```
@method_decorator(industry_required, name='dispatch')
class industryDetails(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = Industry
    template_name = 'app/industryDetails.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Industry.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['inserted_text'] = "inserted text from EmployeeDetails of views.py"
        return context
```

Since each user can however have at most *one* `Industry`, you perhaps should *not* add a primary key to the URL. You thus define a path like:

```
path('industryDetails/', views.industryDetails.as_view(), name='industryDetails')
```

and in the view you override the `get_object` method:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

@method_decorator(industry_required, name='dispatch')
class industryDetails(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = Industry
    template_name = 'app/industryDetails.html'

    def get_object(self):
        return get_object_or_404(Industry, user=self.request.user)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['inserted_text'] = "inserted text from EmployeeDetails of views.py"
        return context
```